# unauthorized app alert when trying to run overwolf sample app

Tags: javascript, api, sample

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:

http://developers.overwolf.com/documentation/odk-2-0-introduction/creating-your-first-app/

after downloading the sample app the provided I've tried this to make it run:

-Open it from overwolf like they say in tutorial:

[image]

-Opening Index.html in Chrome:

[image]

they talk about being white-listed to create an app, I contacted them and I still waiting response, my question is the next:

*How do I create an overwolf app?

*What are the tools to run/debug/compile?

*Any clearer tutorial than theirs?

[ if this is a very stupid question you can be rude XD ]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that if you are not white-listed you can't event run the sample app..... After being white-listed It Worked

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but it turns out that since then they have enabled "Sample App" from running even if you're not whitelisted.

With that information, as long as your "manifest.json" file has the same "meta" as the Sample app, within your application you can run/do whatever you want, as well as change any other aspect of the manifest file and OverWolf will run the app.

I have tested it and it seems to work.

Comment: nice to hear that, it makes more sense this way.